# Assertion Failed: Using `{{view}}` has been removed in Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have upgrade ember version in my project and got some exceptions :

> Assertion Failed: Using `{{view}}` or any path based on it
>   ('path/c-text.hbs' @ L1:C0) has been removed in
>   Ember 2.0

how I should change

> {{view}}

command?

Comment: Replace views with components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view) in Ember 2.0, you can use the [ember-legacy-views](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-views) addon to add them back in.

> This addon enables legacy view support without deprecation notices in Ember.js 1.13. In Ember.js 2.0 views are not present at all, and this addon brings them back. After Ember 2.4 is released this addon will no longer be compatible with Ember. It should be used to provide extra time for migrating away from views, not as a permanent solution.